# Can't get Network in User-Mode-Linux

Tags: networking, linux-kernel, user-mode-linux

I am developing a kernel feature, using User-Mode-Linux.
I compiled 3.12.38 from source and downloaded a Debian fs.
However, I am not able to seet-up networking using following options [here](http://user-mode-linux.sourceforge.net/network.html).
Are there any good source or info to go with this.
I have internet on wlan0.

**EDIT:**
I start with `eth0=tuntap,,,192.168.0.254`

and then inside UML `UML# ifconfig eth0 192.168.0.253 up`
I only get the output as:
`modprobe tun`
`ifconfig tap0 192.168.0.252 netmask 255.255.255.255 up`
`route add -host 192.168.0.253 dev tap0`

As mentioned, output is lacking a bit and more over a **ping** to **192.168.0.254** doesn't seems to work, with 100% packet loss.

Comment: post the errors. and command you executed.

Comment: @Miline Done as requested.

Answer (score 0):

Let us follow the steps to establish the following Topology:

`VM-tap0(192.168.6.6)-------------(192.168.6.8)eth0-UML1-eth1(192.168.20.1)----------------eth1-(192.168.20.2)UML2`

here, UML1 and UML2 are two UML instances running on VM as a host.
All `uml_console` commands are suppose to run on VM host.

`Tun/Tap config:`

**VM <------>UML1 (ley us first establish the connection between VM host and UML1)**

@host as root :

chmod 777 /dev/net/tun

tunctl -u vm -t tap0     (here `vm` is the VM user name)

echo 1 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward

echo 1 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/conf/tap0/proxy_arp

ifconfig tap0 192.168.6.6 up

./linux ubda=CentOS6.x-x86-root_fs umid=debian1 [separate terminal]

uml_mconsole debian1 config eth0=tuntap,tap0

route add -host 192.168.6.8 dev tap0

route add -net 192.168.20.0 netmask 255.255.255.0 gw 192.168.6.8 dev tap0

**@uml1**

eth0=tuntap,tap0

ifconfig eth0 192.168.6.8 up

echo 1 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward

echo 1 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/conf/eth0/proxy_arp

**Now UML1<-------------->UML2**

./linux ubda=CentOS6.x-x86-root_fs2 umid=debian2    [separate terminal]

uml_mconsole debian1 config eth1=mcast (if these commands fails, it means you have not compile the UML kernel with multicast ineterface enabled in )

uml_mconsole debian2 config eth1=mcast

**again @uml1**

ifconfig eth1 192.168.20.1 up

**@uml2**

ifconfig eth1 192.168.20.2 up

route add -net 192.168.6.0 netmask 255.255.255.0 gw 192.168.20.1 dev eth1

echo 1 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward

echo 1 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/conf/eth1/proxy_arp

Try ping UML2 from VM and vice versa. You should be able to ping in both directions.